# How to solve "ssh: connect to host ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out" error in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

1. I am trying to connect to my AWS EC2 instance from `gitbash` in windows10 machine.
2. I am using the below command in ssh.

   > ssh: connect to host ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
3. I have tried connecting from a terminal in linux machine also, But same

   > "connection times out"

errors is what i get.
2. Tried Putty but i get the same error as abiove

> UserName@PC-NAME1 MINGW64 /c
>   $ ssh -i "portfolioec2key.pem" ubuntu@ec-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
>   ssh: connect to host ec2-3-94-109-39.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Yes. 
Inbound rules are below.
Type    Protocol     Port Range      Source
SSH      TCP          22                XX.XX.XX.XX/32(custom)

Comment: Hello Guys if you face the error even after al;l your security groups are good plus you are connecting from corporate ip... then it means that your administrator is blocking or doing somethign which is preventing you from connecting to your aws ec2 instance.

Comment: So what i did is i installed a terminus app and added a all tcp rule connected using telnet protocol from port 33. pls note to copy the username , dns, and keep the key downloaded in mobile. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**step 1**
Go to >Security Groups>Inbound Rules

**Step 2**
[image]

Edit inbond rules and add My Ip inside the highlighted area

Answer (score 0):

1)check pem file permission. 
change pem file permission to 600

```
chmod 600 portfolioec2key.pem
```

2) try to telnet you EC2 instance ip address

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 22.
```

if succeeded  then there is issue with your pem file if not then check below things.

3) Check security group inbound rule.

4) Check NACL .

5) Check your instance is in public subnet or not.

6) If your having VPN connectivity check your instance is in right subnet and having proper connection.